# AucTeX Plain TeX view refresh

Tags: auctex, pdf-tools

I write *TeX in emacs with AucTeX, using pdf-tools as the viewer.
When I compile a LaTeX document in AucTeX with `C-c C-c` the viewer in the other window automatically refreshes, but this does not happen when writing a plain TeX document. How do I enable it?

Comment: Can you give some more information about the way you customised Emacs to use pdf-tools and how you switch from LaTeX to TeX?